# ATG to Microservices

Tags: mysql, mongodb, microservices, atg

We are trying to move away from legacy ATG framework to open source Framework like Spring+JPA+Memcache. As a first step we decided to migrate product catalog module to MicroServices. Which is the right approach, convert ATG repository layer to JPA and write microservices on top that or come with a NoSql data model and replicate the data and consume it using microservices. At this stage, we are not in a condition to completely remove catalog repository from system ,because some other modules also consuming the catalog module data. Question is how to sync MySql db to mongoDB in regular basis?

Comment: Why not simply upgrade to 11.3?  It supports headless commerce and microservices.

Comment: There are way too many options here. It depends what you want to achieve. I'm running 11.3 in production and as @bated says it gives you options. That said you are leaning toward one stack while someone else may lean towards the likes of JAX-RS/Redis/Nginx or any other combination of technologies. Perhaps ask a different more specific question as you'll either get no architecture from this forum, or you'll get 100 different ones (but probably 0).